# Why AddRef returns zero

Tags: c++, assembly, com, iwebbrowser2

I'm debugging C++/COM application, looking at how we AddRef and Release COM objects. I came around weird case when AddRef returns 0. Here is how I get the return value:

```
ULONG TraceAddRef(LPUNKNOWN pUnk, const std::string &a_msg) {
    ULONG count = pUnk->AddRef(); // count == 0 at some point after execution
    ATLTRACE("%s *** AddRef:  pUnk = 0x%p, referenceCount = %lu\n", a_msg.c_str(), pUnk, count);
    return count;
}
```

pUnk is actually IWebBrowser2 COM interface to a web control:

```
pUnk    0x20d763ac  IUnknown *
__vfptr 0x5d85b0d8  const CFrameWebOC::`vftable'{for `IWebBrowser2'}
```

I've looked into Disassembly (Debug build mode) for that line:

```
    ULONG count = pUnk->AddRef();
6515A52C  mov         eax,dword ptr [pUnk]  
6515A52F  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
6515A531  mov         esi,esp  
6515A533  mov         edx,dword ptr [pUnk]  
6515A536  push        edx  
6515A537  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
6515A53A  call        eax  
6515A53C  cmp         esi,esp  
6515A53E  call        _RTC_CheckEsp (65323F90h)  
6515A543  mov         dword ptr [count],eax
```

At that moment `eax` is 0 on the line `6515A543`.

In the debugger when I go into the line `6515A53A`, there it will show the following code:

```
    CFrameWebOC::AddRef:
5D707B6D  mov         edi,edi  
5D707B6F  push        ebp  
5D707B70  mov         ebp,esp  
5D707B72  push        edi  
5D707B73  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
5D707B76  inc         dword ptr [edi-18h]  
5D707B79  cmp         dword ptr [edi-18h],2  
5D707B7D  je          CFrameWebOC::AddRef+26h (5D707B93h)  
5D707B7F  test        dword ptr [edi-4],0FFFFFFFCh  
5D707B86  jne         5DF2DD04  
5D707B8C  xor         eax,eax  
5D707B8E  pop         edi  
5D707B8F  pop         ebp  
5D707B90  ret         4  
5D707B93  push        esi  
5D707B94  lea         esi,[edi-8]  
5D707B97  call        CTrackerHelper::SetAsRoot (5D85AD2Fh)  
5D707B9C  pop         esi  
5D707B9D  jmp         CFrameWebOC::AddRef+12h (5D707B7Fh)  
5D707B9F  nop
```

On the line `5D707B76` the value `dword ptr [edi-18h]` seems to be a reference counter, the value of which is correct, non-zero before and after the `inc` command.

I know that the return value of AddRef is for debugging purposes only. AddRef returning 0 seems like a bug. Can this bug affect the behavior of COM objects I'm using, lifetime in particular?

If that helps I'm on Win7 64bit inside of VirtualBox, using MSVS 2010. The DLL AddRef is in: mshtml.dll

```
mshtml.dll  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll  Symbols loaded (source information stripped).   C:\SYMBOLS\PUBLIC\mshtml.pdb\049E32F8F9F84F8EB494D8324AC1C3112\mshtml.pdb   104 10.00.9200.16521 (win8_gdr_soc_ie.130216-2100)  10/24/2013 8:37 PM  5D380000-5E137000   [0x21DFC] MyApplication.exe: Native
```

Comment: xor eax,eax certainly will return 0.  It does quack like an error return with the jump to 5DF2DD04 expected to be taken.  Unusual.

Comment: I suspect the actual object may be a singleton, never actually freed, and so the reference counting is ignored. But the return value really isn't intended to be relied on, so I wouldn't worry.  The contract is that the object must remain valid if you have a reference; everything else is optional.

Comment: The MSDN documentation does say explicitly about the return value, "This value is intended to be used only for test purposes."

Comment: @AlanStokes: Yeap, it can even be a singleton allocated not in dynamic memory (for example it can be a file level C++ variable) with `Release()` doing nothing and returning zero. That looks creepy but works just fine.

Comment: The MSHTML objects intentionally return 0 for `AddRef` to avoid people taking dependencies on the reference count. You can use the chk build of `mshtml.dll` when debugging. That version returns the reference count from `AddRef`.

Answer (score 2):

It does seem weird, but Alan's guess sound about right. Returning zero from AddRef should not affect anything inside COM because as you mention the value is used for debugging only.